# Centering issues with multiple authors with the same affiliation, EPTCS format

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am using the [EPTCS LaTeX style](http://style.eptcs.org/). This is (a minimal part of) the example that comes with it:

```
\documentclass[adraft]{eptcs}

\title{Title}
\author{
    % first author
    Rob van Glabbeek
    \institute{School of Computer Science and Engineering\\
    University of New South Wales\\
    Sydney, Australia}
    \email{rvg@cs.stanford.edu}
\and
    % two other authors (common affiliation)
    Co Author \qquad\qquad Yet S. Else
    \institute{Stanford Univeristy\\
    California, USA}
    \email{\quad is@gmail.com \quad\qquad somebody@else.org}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Spacing is done by putting some `\quad` and `\qquad`. However, centering stuff by hand quickly becomes annoying when there are more authors, longer names, affiliations and emails of different length, etc...

Is there a better (possibly automatic) way to properly center authors (and their emails) having common affiliations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following commands to your preamble:

```
\RequirePackage{array}
\newenvironment{authors}[1]%
  {\begingroup
   \newcommand\estyle{}%
   \renewcommand\institute[1]%
     {\\\multicolumn{#1}{@{}c@{}}{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\footnotesize}c@{}}##1\end{tabular}}}%
   \renewcommand\email[1]%
     {\gdef\estyle{\footnotesize\ttfamily}\\##1\gdef\estyle{}}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}*{#1}{>{\estyle}c}@{}}
  }%
  {\end{tabular}%
   \endgroup
  }
```

Then you can add multiple authors with the same affiliation but different email addresses to the `\author` command as follows:

```
\author{
  % ... (insert >= 0 authors that do not share affiliations)
  % then come the authors that *do* share an affiliation
  \begin{authors}{NUMBER OF AUTHORS}
    Name1 & Name2 & ...
    \institute{Common\\Affiliation}
    \email{Email1 & Email2 & ...}
  \end{authors}
}
```

For your example this part reads

```
\author{
    Rob van Glabbeek
    \institute{
      School of Computer Science and Engineering\\
      University of New South Wales\\
      Sydney, Australia
    }
    \email{rvg@cs.stanford.edu}

    \and

    \begin{authors}{2}
      Co Author & Yet S. Else
      \institute{Stanford Univeristy\\ California, USA}
      \email{is@gmail.com & somebody@else.org}
    \end{authors}
}
```

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
\documentclass[adraft]{eptcs}
\RequirePackage{array}
\newenvironment{authors}[1]%
  {\begingroup
   \newcommand\estyle{}%
   \renewcommand\institute[1]%
     {\\\multicolumn{#1}{@{}c@{}}{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\footnotesize}c@{}}##1\end{tabular}}}%
   \renewcommand\email[1]%
     {\gdef\estyle{\footnotesize\ttfamily}\\##1\gdef\estyle{}}
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}*{#1}{>{\estyle}c}@{}}
  }%
  {\end{tabular}%
   \endgroup
  }
\title{Title}
\author{
    Rob van Glabbeek
    \institute{
      School of Computer Science and Engineering\\
      University of New South Wales\\
      Sydney, Australia
    }
    \email{rvg@cs.stanford.edu}

    \and

    \begin{authors}{2}
      Co Author & Yet S. Else
      \institute{Stanford Univeristy\\California, USA}
      \email{is@gmail.com & somebody@else.org}
    \end{authors}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem has been recognized by the LaTeX style maintainer and this answer is now suggested as a possible solution in the example page.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like a stack could be helpful here...

```
\documentclass[adraft]{eptcs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\title{Title}
\author{
    % first author
    Rob van Glabbeek
    \institute{School of Computer Science and Engineering\\
    University of New South Wales\\
    Sydney, Australia}
    \email{rvg@cs.stanford.edu}
\and
    % two other authors (common affiliation)
    \Longunderstack{Co Author$^*$, \\ Yet S. Else$^\dag$}\smallskip 
    \institute{Stanford Univeristy\\
    California, USA}
    \email{\Longunderstack{$^*$is@gmail.com,\\ $^\dag$somebody@else.org}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the Stanford names and emails locally left aligned, while at the same time retaining the overall centered appearance, then this:

```
\documentclass[adraft]{eptcs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\title{Title}
\author{
    % first author
    Rob van Glabbeek
    \institute{School of Computer Science and Engineering\\
    University of New South Wales\\
    Sydney, Australia}
    \email{rvg@cs.stanford.edu}
\and
    % two other authors (common affiliation)
    \Longunderstack[l]{Co Author$^*$, \\ Yet S. B. Else$^\dag$}\smallskip 
    \institute{Stanford Univeristy\\
    California, USA}
    \email{\Longunderstack[l]{$^*$is@gmail.com,\\ $^\dag$somebody@else.org}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it makes sense. It could be used when the authors are just too many to fit in a single line.